# Replacing a string

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a URL and I need to replace some string with empty string but when I went through the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) to find the regex expression to use, I couldn't find a suitable pattern that matches what I wanted to do hence my question.

Here is the URL.

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Desired result

```
www.example.com
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Is it allways http:// and / you want to cut?

Comment: `String url = new URI("http://www.example.com/").getPath()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourString = "http://www.example.com/".replaceAll(".*?(www.*?)/","$1");
    System.out.println(yourString);
}
```

O/P :

```
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick without using regex.

```
String host = new URI("http://www.example.com/").getHost();
```

you get www.example.com as output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (your question is not very clear) you can use a pattern like

```
https?://([^/\s]+)/?
```

and replace it with `$1`

This will replace both `visit http://example.com/ now` and `visit https://example.com now` with `visit example.com now`

Edit: refine expression. Now the trailing `/` is optional (but there has to be whitespace after the url in that case!)